# Category List for Youtube Videos (API)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I was wondering if there is a list of available categories where videos can be uploaded to YouTube (programmatically, that is). I have found [this](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories) but to be honest I don't know what part is supposed to be meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list).

`part` can be either `id` or `snippet` (which includes the category names).

You also need to provide a `regionCode` (e.g. `US`) or the list of category IDs you want.

At the end of the documentation page there's a form where you can test it.